# How to ensure authentication while designing a system for downloading files?

Tags: java, download, sftp, system-design

How will I ensure the authenticity of users while downloading a file? I am trying to figure out how to design such a system so that files can be securely downloaded with resume/pause capabilities?

Currently, I tried serving the files through my java-middleware so when client requests for the assets, the client will send the `jwt` token with the request which will ensure authenticity and then java-middleware will connect with the file server which will send back to the response the middleware which in turn server the file to the client. 
But the download is consistently failing and not I am not able to provide resume/pause functionality.

I thought of directly serving the files through SFTP server to the client but then how to ensure the request is authenticated is not clear to me.

Can someone guide me what and how should the above download be achieved?

EDIT:

The file downloaded is not static it is dynamically generated per user, and contains meta-data about the user.

To be more precise the file to be downloaded is a .msi installer which should be linked to an account to be installed on the system. Hence I have to package the downloaded installer with the user-authorization account token so that when user double clicks on it should be installed as per user context .

Comment: Isn't a simple web server with some authorization sufficient for your need? Why would you complicate the system by adding in sftp? Is there anything beyond what a web server can do that you need but you didn't mentioned?

Comment: @glee8e the file to be downloaded is not static, I have to create the download package on the go as per user specific authentication token

Comment: then it make even more sense ro just serve the file through http. The request trigger the generation, and the request wait while the file is generated, then the request stream back the content when it is all finished. If the generation tale too long you may need to use some sort of async or use long poll.